# How do I suppress flicker from the webbrowser control in .Net, when it is resized?

Tags: .net, browser, resize, flicker

Not all pages do this, but a good example would be youtube.com. Mostly if you are resizing the window larger, opposed to smaller. Lots of content flickers horribly in this case. I've seen some posts on the net attempt to claim sorts of double buffering will stop this, but I've yet to see any example of the proper implementation. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Handle the Resize event of the form containing the WebBrowser control.

In this event force the Form (and child controls) to update themselves.  It's a bit unintuitive but this greatly reduces flickering in my application.

```
   private void Form1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
   { 
       this.Update();      
   }
```